# How do I pass a workbook name to a subroutine?

Tags: excel, vba, function, parameters

My first week working with VBA so please be gentle.
I have inherited this code too so a double whammy.
A main Sub calls a Public Function Readfile passing Workbook and Object variables as parameters.
I need to add a Workbook to be used as a look up. I have used Application.GetOpenFilename to prompt the user with a browse window to select this new workbook however adding the workbook variable as a parameter to the Function call doesn't seem to pass the workbook name through. A MsgBox confirms that the variable inside the Function is "nothing".
Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: You'll need to show your code to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry how do I embed code here?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you post the code. But anyway try this.

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim wbk As String
    Dim WB1 As Workbook

    Sub main()
    wbk = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*), *.*")
    getname (wbk)
    End Sub

    Function getname(WkBk As String)
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(WkBk)
    MsgBox WB1.Name
    End Function
```

This code will open the selected workbook and a message box of the name of the workbook.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That works great in isolation. I've tried to use the same code in mine (which was not widely different) but I get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" with highlighting on a line after a "then" where a date is assigned. This seems to be unrelated.Commenting out this line "Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(fdfWB)" and the code works as it did before. I'm confused.

Comment: Not sure how that happened. Can you please post the part of your code where the error occours? so that it would be easy to figure out.

Comment: Sorry there is no problem with your code. It's my end. I found that the vlookup workbook was persisting so I had to close it. This means that I have to open and close it each time I perform the vlookup. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Since I have a line to open the workbook it is necessary to close the workbook. Else can also check if the workbook is open. if not open the workbook else continue with the code. Cheers.